# PAM50 gene expression classification

Tags: r, rna-seq

I'm looking at running the PAM50 classifier on RNA-Seq from 138 breast cancer samples. However, the R package (`genefu`) that's useful for this does not have a particularly helpful `vignette` when it comes to processing the RNAseq counts because it uses pre-processed publicly-available RNAseq data.

1. Starting from counts, is there a way to pre-process the data for running `intrinsic.cluster.predict` in `R/genefu` using the built-in signatures? (I probably won't have enough power to split the set into a training/test set).
2. The best choices for the parameters in `intrinsic.cluster.predict` would also be very helpful.

For differential expression (I have pre and post surgery pairs), I have used conditional quantile normalisation to get normalised log2(RPKM) values for running through `R/EdgeR`, so I also have these available if that is the best way to go.

---

EDIT: looking at the `genefu` vignette, this is all based on microarray data (which is essentially log2(expression)+offset), so will adding an offset to the log2(RPKM) values improve prediction for PAM50?